# Is it possible to store Objects in redis against Lock key while Acquiring redisson Distributed Locks

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, concurrency, redisson

We are using redisson's distributed locks in order to avoid concurrency issue in our distributed environment but while acquiring the lock I also want to save some meta data like userId (random UUID) to know who acquired the lock, **but the contingency is that I can't make the userId part of the key**.

So please help me out if we can store some custom metadata with lock-key in redis distributed locks, or if there's any work around to get similar result.

```
 RLock lock = redisson.getFairLock("anyLock");//if we can store some custom data with the lock key.
lock.lock();
try {
  ...
} catch {
  lock.unlock();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use locks bounded to Map entries.

```
RMap map = redisson.getMap("myMap");
RLock lock = map.getLock("key");
lock.lock();
try {
  map.put("key", value);
} catch {
  lock.unlock();
}
```